# javascript file in flask app doesn't load

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a javascript file that I want to include in HTML while using flask. The js file seems to load, but does not execute.
I did add the javascript file to a folder 'static/js' and am loading it like suggested in many places.
However, the console is empty when starting the app. Any ideas?

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/test.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

static/js/test.js

```
console.log('Test')
```

Comment: Try adding type='text/javascript` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `type='text/javascript'` attribute to `script` tag in your template `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/test.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your index.html should look like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    do something....
    <script src="/static/JS/test.js"></script>
    <!--Add this-->
</body>
</html>
```